# how to use sub query with st_distance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run a subquery inside st_distance but it gives me invalid geometry

My subquery

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )')) as centroid;
  centroid  
------------
 POINT(0 0)
(1 row)
```

I tried few ways

**First way**

```
select ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::geometry, "SRID=4326;(SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )'))) as centroid"::geometry);
NOTICE:  identifier "SRID=4326;(SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )'))) as centroid" will be truncated to "SRID=4326;(SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0,"
ERROR:  column "SRID=4326;(SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0," does not exist
LINE 1: ...ect ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::geometry, "SRID=4326...
```

**2nd way**

```
select ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::geometry, 'SRID=4326;(SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(''MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )''))) as centroid'::geometry);
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
LINE 1: ...ect ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::geometry, 'SRID=4326...
                                                             ^
HINT:  "SRID=4326;(S" <-- parse error at position 12 within geometry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the subquery out of the `st_distance` function.

```sql
SELECT ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::geometry, subqry.centroid)
FROM 
 (SELECT ST_Centroid('SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )'::geometry) as centroid
 ) as subqry;
```

But if you have a single harcoded input, you don't need a subquery at all

```sql
SELECT ST_Distance('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::geometry, 'SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )'::geometry);
```

And last but not least, it is meaningless to compute distances in 4326 using geometries, as the output will be in degrees but a degree of latitude doesn't have the same ground length as a degree of longitude. You might want to cast to `geography` instead of `geometry` to get a distance in meters